# Do I need different paint buckets for different colors?

Tags: paint

I am planning to paint one of my room and the plan is to paint like:

- Ceiling with Ultra white ( Egg shell ),
- three walls with off white ( Egg shell ),
- one wall with dark blue ( probably semi gloss.. yet to decide ).

Do I need 3 different buckets? One for each color. Or do you think bucket can be reused for different colors? Can it be washed completely?

Comment: What do you need a bucket for? The paint comes in buckets from the vendor to begin with....

Comment: You need two if you are going to do a different colour with each hand.

Comment: @Solar mike .. `With each hand`.. Sorry didnt get you.

Comment: @SolarMike  :-) ... lol

Comment: @RakeshJuyal Mike is joking; he means you only need more than one colour if you are going to be painting with more than one colour at the same time. If you are painting each colour separately (which presumably you are), and you wash the bucket in between, then one bucket is enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using latex paint so using the same roller pan/ bucket will be no problem. They clean up really good and fast and that's what I've always done. However, they are pretty cheap and many people I know would rather buy a few and just throw the used ones out rather than cleaning them up.

Comment: `They clean up really good and fast and that's what I've always done.` I saw few videos where they said use warm water and dish soap... Is that the method you used?

Comment: @RakeshJuyal  No, I used a hose and high pressure nozzle outside. Wife didn't want me messing up the kitchen..

Comment: Yeah, exactly.  *Latex* aka emulsion paint cleans very easily with soap and water. Alkyds and the advanced 2-part paints most definitely do not!